# Incompatible types in assignment ardunio

Tags: c++, arduino, lidar

Just started getting into Arduino. I bought a mini LIDAR, and I'm just trying to get it working, so I can play with it. This was the only sample code I could find that seemed simple enough to get it running. But it gives the error "incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'int [9]'".
I'm not a programmer yet. Would someone please help me figure out what's wrong with it?

note: the IDE highlight the "uart=Serial1.read();" in the for loop

```
int dist;// LiDAR actually measured distance value
int strength;// LiDAR signal strength
int check;// check numerical value storage
int i;
int uart[9];// store data measured by LiDAR
const int HEADER=0x59;// data package frame header
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);//set the Baud rate of Arduino and computer serial port
  Serial1.begin(115200);//set the Baud rate of LiDAR and Arduino serial port
}
void loop()
{
  if (Serial1.available())//check whether the serial port has data input
  {
    if(Serial1.read()==HEADER)// determine data package frame header 0x59
    {
      uart[0]=HEADER;
      if(Serial1.read()==HEADER)//determine data package frame header 0x59
      {
        uart[1]=HEADER;
        for(i=2;i<9;i++)// store data to array
        {
          uart=Serial1.read();
        }
      check=uart[0]+uart[1]+uart[2]+uart[3]+uart[4]+uart[5]+uart[6]+uart[7];
      if(uart[8]==(check&0xff))// check the received data as per protocols
      {
        dist=uart[2]+uart[3]*256;// calculate distance value
        strength=uart[4]+uart[5]*256;// calculate signal strength value
        Serial.print("dist = ");
        Serial.print(dist);// output LiDAR tests distance value
        Serial.print('\t');
        Serial.print("strength = ");
        Serial.print(strength);// output signal strength value
        Serial.print('\n');
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: `uart=Serial1.read()` -> `uart[i] = Serial1.read()`?

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve].  Your post is okay, but it doesn't point to the line of code where you got the error.  The error message indicates you are trying to assign an int to an array of int, not to one of the positions in that array.

Comment: You probably want `uart[i]=Serial1.read()`.

Comment: @KamilCuk yes! thank you

Comment: @jwdonahue yep! thanks